# Creating a launch file for running 3 separate nodes

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I would like to activate 3 nodes of which I created 1. The other 2 are prebuilt nodes and each has a launch file.
My nodes are as follows:

**I want to create a launch file for this node coming after rosrun:**

$ rosrun hand_raise_detector armraiselistener.py

**The file should trigger below nodes coming after roslaunch:**

$ roslaunch realsense_camera sr300_nodelet_rgbd.launch

$ roslaunch openpose_ros openpose_ros.launch

**EDIT for solution:**

```
<launch>
     <node pkg="hand_raise_detector" type="armraiselistener.py" name="armraiselistener" output="screen"/>
     <include file="/home/robolab3/catkin_ws/src/openpose_ros-master/openpose_ros/launch/openpose_ros.launch" />
     <include file="/home/robolab3/catkin_ws/src/realsense/realsense_camera/launch/sr300_nodelet_rgbd.launch" />
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287467/creating-a-launch-file-for-running-3-separate-nodes/) by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-04**:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The setup you've described is fairly standard for a roslaunch file, and should be pretty straight forward to put together. In short you are just creating a launch file which runs your node and includes the launch files for the existing packages you are running. The skeleton will look something like this:

```
<launch>
     <node pkg="package_name" type="node" name="name" />
     <include file="$(find ros_package_name)/path_to_launch.launch" />
     <include file="$(find ros_package_name)/path_to_launch.launch" />
</launch>
```

Check out the wiki page on roslaunch [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch), and if you need further help there is a very thorough chapter (Chapter 6) in the book "A Gentle Introduction to ROS" which is available for free [here](https://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/agitr-letter.pdf). If you still can't get it working after you've looked through all of that update your question with the attempt you've made and I'm sure someone will help troubleshoot!

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-04-04**:
This works thank you. I have encountered a warning though. Do you know why I get this? My xml is below as well.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-04-04**:
Your node name is illegal (have a read of the [page](http://wiki.ros.org/Names) linked in the error message)

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-04-06**:
I posted working code in the answer. Thanks for the help!